# Is the Silverlight 4 SDK download corrupted?

Tags: sdk, silverlight-4.0, download, corruption, corrupt

I downloaded the Silverlight 4 SDK (not the Beta) from the following Microsoft site.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=55B44DA3-E5DE-4D2A-8EAF-1155CA6B3207&displaylang=en

However, when I try to run the file, it says "File is corrupt".

Has anyone else also faced this issue?

Is there any other site from which I can download the SDK?

Please let me know...

TIA,

Sudeep

Answer (score 0):

That link doesn't work for me at all.

This is the link I think you want to use [Microsoft Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b3deb194-ca86-4fb6-a716-b67c2604a139&displaylang=en)

Go here and use the web platform installer perhaps: http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/